# What is the alternative way of not to use dictionary because order not same all time?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I am get data from Server which i convert into Dictionary using #SwiftyJson. When i iterate this dictionary item not showing same order all time.Different its show different Order.How can I get the same order which one give me from server? Here is my response data..

{

```
content = "what type you like?";
"demoID" = 6;
suggestion =     {
    "example 1" = "Blonde";
    "example 2" = "Dark";
    "example 3" = "Dirty";

};
```

}

This code use with #SwiftJson

if let responseDict = responseData.dictionary, let suggestion = responseDict["suggestion"]?.dictionary {

}

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries in swift are always unsorted by design! If you want to have it sorted, you need to use another data structure like an array.

Comment: at least tell me why you down voted me?

Comment: I am also looking for solution but they did down vote to me

Comment: Can you pls convert my code in to Array?Or what should i write for Array?

Comment: you can simply do var array = ["Blonde", "Dark", "Dirty"]

Comment: I get the data from sever when i want convert this into array its show error

Comment: are you the one writing the server code? it would be easier to change it to an array from there to be honest